# Implicitly qualified autowiring in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a project with some independent bean X, that is autowired in a bunch of services. Services are used by each other, and finally used in single entry point (controller). Now there is new requirement: implement several versions of X, and decide witch one is to use according to entry point's parameter (enum XType). It would be nice to do it without changing services.

My idea of solution is to create custom scope UsesX and implement `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, that will converts each `BeanDefinition` with UsesX to set of singletons for each XType. Also, it will adds qualifiers to this beans, to make it possible to make factory method for X and parameter-based selection in controller. But how to add this qualifier to `@Autowired` in services implicitly, without changing their classes?

**UPD**

Ok, example, I want to use db url `"jdbc:mysql://Adb"` when `A` requested, and `"jdbc:mysql://Bdb"` when `B`:

```
enum DatabaseType {A, B}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(/)
class MyController {
@Autowired ServiceProvider provider; // some way to get service by DatabaseType
    void foo(@RequestParam DatabaseType dbType) {
       ServiceA a = provider.getA(dbType);
       a.bar();
       ServiceB b = provider.getB(dbType);
       b.baz();
    }
}

@Service
class ServiceA {
    // Don't want to get information about different databases in services
    @Autowired ServiceB b;
    @Autowired ServiceC c;
    @Autowired DaoFoo dao;
    //...
}

@Service
class ServiceB {
    @Autowired ServiceC c;
    @Autowired DaoFoo daoFoo;
    @Autowired DaoBar daoBar;
    //...
}

@Service
class ServiceC {
    @Autowired DaoBar daoBar;
    //...
}

@Repository
class DaoFoo {
    DaoFoo(String dbURL) {/*...*/}
}

@Repository
class DaoBar {
    DaoFoo(String dbURL) {/*...*/}
}
```

Also, it is required to `"jdbc:mysql://Adb"` and `"jdbc:mysql://Bdb"` be configured in XML configuration.

Comment: Very unclear what is being asked. Is ServiceA suppose to use Adb and ServiceB suppose to use Bdb?? Even then this question still makes 0 sense

Answer (score 3):

I want to wrap up your requirements so that it would be clear if I'm getting you right.

1. You have a set of `@Service`s that you don't want to modify.
2. At this moment you have only one implementation of `X` type which is used by this services.
3. The choice of `X` implementation to be used in services would be defined by `XType` enum, which in turn would be available from request.
4. You want `X` type beans be configurable from `xml`.

OP: What `X` implementation should be used in case if one of this services would be called w/o `XType`?

So if my understanding is correct, it seems like you need `Proxy` for `X` type.
Within this `Proxy` you need to get this `XType` implicitly (f.ex. through `ThreadLocal` var).
As `@Autowired` is used, beans are identified by type in first place. Therefore, you need to use already existing `X` implementation for proxing and extract your current implementation and new one to different type.

As a result you might end up with following:

```
interface newX {
    void save();
}

@Repository
class DaoFoo implements newX {
    public void save() {...};
}

@Repository
class DaoBar implements newX {
    public void save() {...};
}

class XImpl implements X, newX {
    public final ThreadLocal<XType> currentXType = new ThreadLo...;
    Map<XType, newX> mapping = ....
    public void save() {mapping.get(currentXType.get()).save();};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a little confusing because your `Service`s are named A and B, but you also use A and B for your `DatabaseType`. But I think I understand what you want.

I don't think you can do this with `Autowired`, but you can make your `Service`s as `@Scope("prototype")` and retrieve them from context. The context should instantiate the `Service` the first time you request it, then reuse the same bean when the same input is provided.

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceProvider{
    ...
    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public ServiceA serviceA(DatabaseType dbType) {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public ServiceB serviceB(DatabaseType dbType) {
        ...
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(/)
class MyController {
    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context
    void foo(@RequestParam DatabaseType dbType) {
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getBeanFactory();
        ServiceA serviceA = (ServiceA)context.getBean("serviceA", dbType);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a service interface like :

```
interface ServiceInterface{
    public boolean isTheOne(String type); // or some suitable name.
}
```

all your services then need to implement this interface, then in controller

```
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping(/)
   class MyController {
   @Autowired 
   Set<ServiceInterface> provider; 

   void foo(@RequestParam DatabaseType dbType) {
     ServiceInterface service = provider.stream().filter(s -> s.isTheOne(String dbType));
     service.bar();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain your XType as an enumerator within a customised `Qualifier` by developing `@Interface`.
Please find below a sample which mentions conditional wiring of beans based upon different types of datatype:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, 
         ElementType.METHOD,
         ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public static @interface DBHost{

public static enum DatabaseType {      
A,
B
}
}


@Autowired
@DBHost(DBHost.DatabaseType.A)
ServiceBean serviceInstanceA;
```

Find additional usage of Qualifier annotation [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier)